# Data grid checkbox disable un-checked option for key

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, checkbox

I'm using `DataGrid` and I have one column with a`Checkbox`. I would like that whenever a row has the key, the checkbox will be disabled so as to the user cannot uncheck it.
I have a property in my view model which is called `IsKey` with `INotifyPropertyChanged`. How can I do that?

the `IsChecked` binding is that all the `Checkboxes` are checked when starting 
the `DataGrid` and user can uncheck rows, besides keys...

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBox" 
          IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
   </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Comment: Update the IsEnabled property with the help of Converters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `IsKey` is `bool` you can use `Style.Triggers` so when `IsKey` is true set `IsEnabled` to false:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="CheckBox" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <CheckBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsKey}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </CheckBox.Style>
</CheckBox>
```

Comment: Perfect..i like it :)